# Add headers in webview

Tags: android, webview

Is it possible to add extra headers in a webView when i am using **loadData** function?

I found this
       **loadUrl(String url, Map extraHeaders)**
but this applies the headers to the requests only what if i want to add headers with loadData method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to add extra headers in a webView when i am using loadData function?

No, because there is no server to interpret the headers, and so they would be useless.

Answer (score 0):

Create xml file with header and webview and then

Use this it will work.

```
String mresult = "<html><head></head><body><p>Testing here</p></body></html>"

web.loadData(mresult, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
```